# How do i convert curl to powershell

Tags: rest, powershell, curl

How do i convert this curl command to powershell? This works perfectly using curl however in powershell i am geting 401 unauthorized.
I have tried everything i can think of. This code can only be executed inside a certain environment. i am trying to pass a cookie i know is valid into the header of the second. The first request works well, the second request which is meant the return json does not. Instead returns 401

The command requires cookies to authenitcate

```
curl.exe -vu SuperGabriel:SuperGabriel@2019 -X POST -H "X-Application: 3rdParty" https://webadmin.td90.centile-dev.com/restletrouter/v1/service/Login --insecure
curl.exe -v -H "Cookie: thirdParty_SESSIONID=6483556424564819468" -H "X- 
               Application: 3rdParty" https://webadmin.td90.centile-dev.com/restletrouter/v1/3rdParty/AdmtiveDomain --insecure
curl.exe -v -H "Cookie: thirdParty_SESSIONID=1312545750448673312" -H "X-Application: 3rdParty" https://webadmin.td90.centile-dev.com/restletrouter/v1/3rdParty/CallRecord/0.106.?day=20190301 -k --insecure -o
"C:\Users\stephenm\Documents\test.csv"
```

Here is my powershell code so far.

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
    }
}
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object 
TrustAllCertsPolicy
$user = "SuperGabriel"
$pass = "SuperGabriel@2019" 
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"

$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$headers = @{
"Authorization" = $basicAuthValue
"X-Application" = "3rdParty"
}



 $login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://webadmin.td90.centile-dev.com/restletrouter/v1/service/Login  -Headers $headers  -Method Post 


$headers = @{
"Authorization" = $basicAuthValue
"X-Application" = "3rdParty"
"Cookie" ="thirdParty_SESSIONID=4436753218874838616"
"Content-Type" = "application/json"
}


try
{
$admtiveDomains = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://webadmin.td90.centile- 
dev.com/restletrouter/v1/3rdParty/AdmtiveDomain -Headers $headers  -Method 
Get

}catch{
   echo $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message

}
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you need to get a token first that you then need to convert to a base64 string?

```
$uri = 'https://webadmin.td90.centile-dev.com/restletrouter/v1/service/Login'
$body = @{ username = 'SuperGabriel'; password = 'SuperGabriel@2019' }
$bodyjson = $body | convertTo-Json
$ctype = "application/json"
$token = invoke-restmethod -uri $uri -method POST -body $bodyjson -contenttype $ctype
```

I don't know what object `$token` would return, but you would essentially then convert the returned string and continue on from there.

```
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($token))
```